# Import Google contact with custom Field from csv

Tags: csv, gmail, contacts

I have a csv as

```
First, mobile, id
Tom, 1276546789, 52
rosh, 2764898735, 73
.......
.......
.......
```

I would like to import this contact details in my google account with including the custom field name "ID" and its value.

I found so many option from google search but none of them works. it only insert the name and mobile only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The heading "Organizational ID Number" is valid, it is added as a custom field towards the bottom of the contact page.

I believe "Government ID Number" is also valid but haven't used it myself.